# How can I disable the highlighting of HTML contained in .js/.ts files in Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm, angular

I'm working with Angular 2, and Webstorm doesn't seem quite ready for the template to be sitting right there in the Typescript file.

Specifically, it's highlighting anything that goes between the tilde's (`).

The highlighting is really annoying!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Webstorm, go to:

```
Settings > Editor > Colors and Fonts > General > Code > Injected Language Fragment
```

By default, it's assigned a background color. Just uncheck the box and it'll go away.